# Number of attributes of a case class in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the most efficient way to get the number of attributes of a case class in Scala? I need to do this before any instantiation.

For instance for the case class:

```
Person(name: String, weight: Float)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
Person.attributes_length // returning 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### With an instance

You can make a "fake" instance or if you have one:

```
Person(null, 0).productArity
```

### By reflection

Another option is to use reflection.

#### Scala 2.11

Add the reflection lib to SBT:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.8"
```

And do:

```
weakTypeOf[Person].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.paramLists.size
```

#### Scala 2.10

Add the reflection lib to SBT:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.6"
```

And do:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

weakTypeOf[Person].declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.paramss.head.size
```

Cheers

Comment: It did not work, but you gave me an idea: classOf[Person].getConstructors.head.getParameterTypes.length

Comment: I edited the answer with Scala reflection over weird Java reflection.

Comment: `productArity` is definitely the way to go.  Works great.

Comment: @jwvh: `productarity` requires you to create an instance first. In order to create an instance, you already need to know the arity anyway, and not just the arity, but also the types, and the semantically valid values. It works, assuming that you get an instance from somewhere else and need to obtain its arity, but the question explicitly states "I need to do this before any instantiation."

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I ended up using the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.4"
```

with the code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val length = weakTypeOf[Person].declaration(scala.reflect.runtime.universe.nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod.paramss.head.length
```